# How to deploy DOM object to html

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
  var cell = $("<div></div>");
  for (var j  =0 ; j < items.paths.length ;j++){
     cell.append(item.paths[j]);
   }
      
  $(`<tr><td style="white-space: normal;">
     ${cell}
   </td></tr>`).appendTo('#mytable');
```

I made the dom object named `cell`

And I want to deploy the cell to html, however it shows only `[object Object]`, where am I wrong?

Comment: `${cell}` evaluates to `[object Object]`, beacause it's jQuery object and you're converting it into string. Append cell as td's child with jQuery function

Answer (score 1):

Any object, when coerced into a string will output as `[object Object]`.   Your `cell` variable is an object.

Either build a string or don't; you're mixing the two.

You have a number of options:

- You can build the string in one go (other answer, not repeated here)
- Build `cell` as a string rather than a dom object, eg

```
var cell = "<div>";
for (var j  =0 ; j < items.paths.length ;j++){
  cell += items.paths[j];
}
cell += "</div">
```

*though if doing that then use `.join()`*

```
var cell = "<div>" + items.paths.join(" ") + "</div>";
```

- You could convert the `cell` to a string, eg

```
$(`<tr><td>${cell.html()}</td></tr>`)
```

*note: this will remove the outer `<div></div>`, so maybe `${cell[0].outerHTML}`*

- or you can use DOM manipulation to add the cell content

```
$("<tr><td></td></tr>").appendTo("#tbl").find("td").append(cell);
```

Comment: Up vote for useful details, but note there's also a typo in the original code, i.e., "item" rather than "items"

Comment: @Yogi thanks - hate it when you just copy OPs code and there's additional errors in it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are appending htmlStrings then do it all at once and then use `.join(', ')` to convert the array into a string (no iteration needed).

```js
const items = {
  paths: ["North", "East", "West", "South"]
};

$(`<tr>
     <td style="white-space: normal;">
       <div>${items.paths.join(', ')}</div>
     </td>
   </tr>`).appendTo('table');
```

```css
table, td {border:1px solid black}
```

```html
<table></table>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```